# poetryに"chef.py"というファイルがあります。"chef"とはどのような意味なのでしょうか？

Tags: python, poetry

## 環境

- poetry 1.7.1

## 質問

poetryで`chef.py`というソースがあります。"chef"とはどのような意味なのでしょうか？
https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/blob/master/src/poetry/installation/chef.py#L33

以前`poetry install`コマンドを実行したときに、`ChefBuildError`というエラーに遭遇しました。
エラーの名前だけだと何を表しているのか分からなかったので、名前の由来や意味に興味を持ちました。

"chef"という名前が、もしかしたらpoetry限定の命名ではなく、プログラミング界の用語の命名パターンなのかと思い、質問しました。

## 私の予想

"chef"は「料理人」という意味なので、いろいろ加工するというニュアンスなのでしょうか？

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IT業界のインフラ界隈で[Chef](https://docs.chef.io/workstation/)といえば、構成管理ツールのことを指すのが一般的です。

構成管理ツールからスクリプトや設定ファイルを読込実行することで、下記のように端末の構成を一元管理することができます。

- リモートまたはローカル端末のセットアップを行う
- アプリケーションの設定ファイルなどの変更を検知して通知やロールバックを行う
- 複数端末のアプリケーション構成を一括で変更する

例えばChefからスクリプト(Chefの場合はこのスクリプトを「レシピ」と呼びます)を呼び出すことで、下記の作業をワンアクションで実行できます。

- 新規のLinuxサーバにNginxをインストール
- `nginx.conf`をサーバごとに書き換える
- `/usr/share/nginx/html/`にファイルをインポートする

上記の作業が完了した状態でChefから同じレシピを実行した場合は、サーバ構成は何も変更されずにエラーなくレシピの処理が正常終了します。
何度レシピを実行しても結果が変わらないことで冪等性(べきとうせい)を保つのが、構成管理ツールの理念です。

他に有名な構成管理ツールとしては[Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/index.html)、[Terraform](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform)、[Puppet](https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppet/8/puppet_index.html)などが挙げられます。
構成管理ツールごとに、Chefで使える言語はRubyであったり、AnsibleはPythonであったりとスクリプトの特徴や得意分野が異なります。
ご興味がありましたら特徴や得意分野を把握してツールを選定してください。(AWS専用のAWS CloudFormationなど、環境限定のツールもあります)

ご質問の`Chef.py`はざっと見たところ`prepare`で環境のセットアップをするコードに見えますので、やはり構成管理ツールをふんわりと意識した命名と推測いたします。

ただし私は寡聞にしてChefを接頭辞にする例をあまり聞きませんので、万人に分かりやすい命名規則ではないかもしれません。
「Chef」自体は構成管理ツールを知っている人の認知度が高い用語ですので、意味を把握して損はしないと思います。

参考資料:

- [Ansible、Terraform、Puppet、Chef、Salt について理解する](https://www.redhat.com/ja/topics/automation/understanding-ansible-vs-terraform-puppet-chef-and-salt)
- [[Chef] 冪等性を保つのだ](https://suzuki.tdiary.net/20150515.html)
- [CloudFormation vs Terraform](https://www.qes.co.jp/media/aws/a322)